# Syntax error in SQLite query

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am trying to insert a large number of records into a SQLite database. I get the above error if I try to use the sqlite3_exec C-API.

The code looks like this:

```
ret = sqlite_exec(db_p,".import file.txt table", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I know that the .import   is command line, but can there be any way that you can do a extremely large insert of records that takes minimal time. I have read through previous bulk insert code and attempted to make changes but these are not providing the desired results.

Is there not a way to directly insert the string into the tables without having intermediate API's being called?

Comment: Could you add a snippet of code that is generating SQL and calling `sqlite3_exec`?  This error is usually caused by either a syntax error or formatting error.

Comment: ret = sqlite_exec(db_p,".import file.txt table", NULL, NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 3):

.import is most probably not available via the API. However there's one crucial thing to speed up inserts: wrap them in a transaction.

```
BEGIN;
lots of insert statements here;
COMMIT;
```

Without this, sqlite will need to write to the file after each insert to keep the ACID principle. The transaction let's it write to file later in bulk.

Comment: This is the right answer. SQLite is a library. `.import` and other dot-commands are part of the SQLite shell, which is just a sample program (though official) built upon SQLite. However you should add semicolons after `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

Comment: do I need to have the sqlite3_exec between each transaction for individual inserts that I do here? Thanks :-)

Comment: @SportyMe: take a look at the source code for the shell utility (http://www.sqlite.org/src/annotate?checkin=f85afa0ecc7b31d3&filename=src/shell.c).  Search for `"import"` including the quotes.  They create a transaction using `BEGIN/END`, use a prepared statement for the `INSERT` calling `sql3_bind_text` for each column and `sql3_step` for each row. The code is quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the syntax error could well be, that your strings are not enclosed in quotes in your SQL statement.

Comment: There has to be a way to use the command line equivalents in the C API functions? I have posted the code snippet that the error is reported as above.